# git push error, Permission to Abhiuni799040/mysite.git denied to Abhishek7990. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukhFC.png)

See this image there is a error mentioned. I have tried all the troubleshoot commands available in the stackoverflow . Please help.

Answer (score 1):

May be this would work :

remove the current remote url :

```
git remote remove origin
```

and then try to set the remote url with this command :

```
git remote add origin url_of_github_repo
```